Integral of $\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+a^2)(z-i)^2}$ on the rectangle with corners $z=\pm 1$ and $z=\pm 1 + (1+a)i$, negative way
Note that
$$
\int_{C-}\frac{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}z}}{\left(z^{2} + a^{2}\right)\left(z - {\rm i}\right)^{2}}{\rm d}z =
-\int_{C}\frac{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}z}}
{\left(z^{2} + a^{2}\right)/\left(z - {\rm i}\right)^{2}}
{\rm d}z
$$
And here perhaps I could use Cauchy's integral formula if it were not for a subtlety, that I consider that the function $\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+a^2)}$ it is not analytic on the given curve, since a singularity is $z=ia$, which apparently belongs to such a rectangle.
So to solve such an integral, which is non-zero, a somewhat hidden trick should be done, I think, I do not see a clear way to solve this integral. Any suggestions?
I forgot to mention that $a$ is a positive number other than $1$.

You have identified two singularities in the curve. Think about how you could manipulate the integral (and the curve) to perform Cauchy's integral formula twice. I can give a more complete answer if you're still stuck.

@rkilpadi I have tried to conveniently manipulate the denominator in many ways but to no avail, your answer would be very helpful.

As you have identified, there are exactly two singularities within the bounds of the rectangle at $z=i$ and $z=ai$, which means Cauchy's integral formula cannot be directly applied. One strategy to solve this would be partial fraction decomposition. Instead, you can save yourself some computation by splitting the rectangle into two curves as seen in the image below (from an open textbook on complex analysis):

As you can see in the image, the original circle was redrawn as two partial circles, each containing one singularity. The parts of the curve that are intersecting the circle are pointing in different directions and therefore will cancel each other out. If we let $C$ be our rectangle, we can use the same method to split it into two curves $C_1$ and $C_2$, each containing one singularity. Now we can simply rewrite the integral and apply Cauchy's integral formula twice:
$$-\oint_C\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+a^2)(z-i)^2}\,dz=-\oint_{C_1}\frac{\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+ai)(z-ai)}}{(z-i)^2}\,dz-\oint_{C_2}\frac{\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+ai)(z-i)^2}}{z-ai}\,dz$$
I'll leave the final calculation to you.

Good point, I hadn't thought that it is possible to deform the contours at convenience, but I have a question. In the integral to the right of the whole, shouldn't you have $(z-i)^2$?

Yep, that was a typo. Good catch
